# Error while linking OpenCV

Tags: opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone, I am using ROS Fuerte and in the project that I use OpenCV with ROS I can compile perfectly. The problem is, if I try to compile a project normal project that uses OpenCV (out of ROS), I get errors while linking:

$ make
g++ -Wall -DASSERT -O3 -g `pkg-config opencv --cflags` -o main.o -c main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:44:5: warning: ‘key’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]

g++  `pkg-config opencv --libs` -o main main.o
main.o: In function `main': /home/roleiland/Desktop/video_test/main.cpp:29: undefined reference to` cvCreateFileCapture'
/home/roleiland/Desktop/video_test/main.cpp:39: undefined reference to `cvGetCaptureProperty' /home/roleiland/Desktop/video_test/main.cpp:42: undefined reference to` cvNamedWindow'
/home/roleiland/Desktop/video_test/main.cpp:52: undefined reference to `cvShowImage' /home/roleiland/Desktop/video_test/main.cpp:55: undefined reference to` cvWaitKey'
/home/roleiland/Desktop/video_test/main.cpp:46: undefined reference to `cvQueryFrame' /home/roleiland/Desktop/video_test/main.cpp:59: undefined reference to` cvReleaseCapture'
/home/roleiland/Desktop/video_test/main.cpp:60: undefined reference to `cvDestroyWindow'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1

If I execute:

$ pkg-config opencv --libs

-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_ml -lopencv_nonfree -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_photo -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video -lopencv_videostab

$ ls /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/

libactionlib.so                libopencv_flann.so            libopencv_photo.so.2.4        libpcl_io_ply.so.1.5.1                        libpcl_segmentation.so
libcpp_common.so               libopencv_flann.so.2.4        libopencv_photo.so.2.4.2      libpcl_io.so                                  libpcl_segmentation.so.1.5
libflann_cpp-gd.so             libopencv_flann.so.2.4.2      libopencv_stitching.so        libpcl_io.so.1.5                              libpcl_segmentation.so.1.5.1
libflann_cpp_s.a               libopencv_gpu.so              libopencv_stitching.so.2.4    libpcl_io.so.1.5.1                            libpcl_surface.so
libflann_cpp_s-gd.a            libopencv_gpu.so.2.4          libopencv_stitching.so.2.4.2  libpcl_kdtree.so                              libpcl_surface.so.1.5
libflann_cpp.so                libopencv_gpu.so.2.4.2        libopencv_ts.so               libpcl_kdtree.so.1.5                          libpcl_surface.so.1.5.1
libflann_cpp.so.1.7            libopencv_highgui.so          libopencv_ts.so.2.4           libpcl_kdtree.so.1.5.1                        libpcl_tracking.so
libflann_cpp.so.1.7.1          libopencv_highgui.so.2.4      libopencv_ts.so.2.4.2         libpcl_keypoints.so                           libpcl_tracking.so.1.5
libflann_s.a                   libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.2    libopencv_video.so            libpcl_keypoints.so.1.5                       libpcl_tracking.so.1.5.1
libflann.so                    libopencv_imgproc.so          libopencv_video.so.2.4        libpcl_keypoints.so.1.5.1                     libpcl_visualization.so
libflann.so.1.7                libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4      libopencv_video.so.2.4.2      libpcl_octree.so                              libpcl_visualization.so.1.5
libflann.so.1.7.1              libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4.2    libopencv_videostab.so        libpcl_octree.so.1.5                          libpcl_visualization.so.1.5.1
libmessage_filters.so          libopencv_legacy.so           libopencv_videostab.so.2.4    libpcl_octree.so.1.5.1                        librosbag.so
libopencv_calib3d.so           libopencv_legacy.so.2.4       libopencv_videostab.so.2.4.2  libpcl_range_image_border_extractor.so        librosconsole.so
libopencv_calib3d.so.2.4       libopencv_legacy.so.2.4.2     libpcl_common.so              libpcl_range_image_border_extractor.so.1.5    libroscpp_serialization.so
libopencv_calib3d.so.2.4.2     libopencv_ml.so               libpcl_common.so.1.5          libpcl_range_image_border_extractor.so.1.5.1  libroscpp.so
libopencv_contrib.so           libopencv_ml.so.2.4           libpcl_common.so.1.5.1        libpcl_registration.so                        libroslib.so
libopencv_contrib.so.2.4       libopencv_ml.so.2.4.2         libpcl_features.so            libpcl_registration.so.1.5                    librospack.so
libopencv_contrib.so.2.4.2     libopencv_nonfree.so          libpcl_features.so.1.5        libpcl_registration.so.1.5.1                  librostime.so
libopencv_core.so              libopencv_nonfree.so.2.4      libpcl_features.so.1.5.1      libpcl_sample_consensus.so                    librxtools.so
libopencv_core.so.2.4          libopencv_nonfree.so.2.4.2    libpcl_filters.so             libpcl_sample_consensus.so.1.5                libtopic_tools.so
libopencv_core.so.2.4.2        libopencv_objdetect.so        libpcl_filters.so.1.5         libpcl_sample_consensus.so.1.5.1              libxmlrpcpp.so
libopencv_features2d.so        libopencv_objdetect.so.2.4    libpcl_filters.so.1.5.1       libpcl_search.so                              pkgconfig
libopencv_features2d.so.2.4    libopencv_objdetect.so.2.4.2  libpcl_io_ply.so              libpcl_search.so.1.5                          python2.7
libopencv_features2d.so.2.4.2  libopencv_photo.so            libpcl_io_ply.so.1.5          libpcl_search.so.1.5.1

Any idea about what could be wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62167/error-while-linking-opencv/) by [roleiland](https://answers.ros.org/users/4475/roleiland/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-05-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think this is linking order; the library flags for opencv should be specified **after** the .o files in the linking step:

```
g++ -o main main.o main.o `pkg-config opencv --libs`
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0